# Simple search on dynamic web app content

Tags: asp.net, .net, search

I'm looking to implement search functionality in an ASP.NET MVC site.

The site is driven by a CMS. The users can add widgets to the page with meetings, documents, etc.

So the whole site is fully dynamic.

As I see it, there are 2 options:

- Search all possible content directly, and then figure out what results are coupled to pages. Or the other way around, figure out what the content of a page is.
- Load or construct all available pages, and make sure the content can be searched. So, basically crawling and indexing my own content.

Maybe other?

I'm not sure what the best implementation would be, all experiences and directions are welcome!

I'm not really looking for Solr or Lucene based solutions. This needs to be a simple implementation, just running a LIKE on the correct rows of the DB is suffictient.

Comment: so you want full text search for your web site ?

Comment: Kind of, but since the pages are dynamic. I'm wondering what the best approach is: crawl my own pages and search that (FTS, or simple LIKE's), or, search the content in the database and track back those results to pages.

Comment: What CMS are you using?  Also, you can do really simple implementations with Lucene - we index a collection of Products and use Lucene to search against common fields much as you would using a LIKE against a database.